# Fill gap after circular cut

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

How can I fast make circular wall in mesh, which I've made using curve and Knife project tool?
[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the 'Bridge Edge Loops' tool in the specials menu, accessed by <kbd>W</kbd>.

1. Select the edges around your holes on both sides of the mesh (click to select an edge whilst holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to select edge loops).
2. Open the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd>.
3. Select "*Bridge Edge Loops*" and you should end up with the result you desire.

[image: Bridge Edge Loops process]

Alternatively, you could simply use a boolean modifier with a cylinder. This will automatically create the internal faces.